# Symfony Form Entity with Doctrine Query Builder Subselect

Tags: php, sql, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got a form field that displays a select box of categories - categories can have a parent category which is a self referencing index.

In my form, I only want to display the categories with no parents, so the raw SQL (which works) would look like this:

```
SELECT c.id
FROM category c
WHERE (
     SELECT count( cx.id ) AS cxcount
     FROM category cx
     WHERE cx.parent_id = c.id
) = 0
```

So my Form field looks like this:

```
->add('category', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'AcmeBundleName:Category',
    'query_builder' => function($repository) {
        $qb2 = $repository->createQueryBuilder('cx');
        $qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('c');
        $qb->where(
        $qb->expr()->eq(
            $qb2->select('count(cx.id) AS cxcount')
                ->where('cx.parent_id = c.id')
            , '0')
        );
    return $qb;
},
// rest of field options
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 57: Error: Expected Literal, got 'SELECT'
```

So I've clearly missed something... Is anybody able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: try to dump the sql.

but the sql you write is to display the categories that have no children.